# Not able to get the meta information given to gccxml using __attribute

Tags: xml, linux, gcc

I am trying to use the `__attribute` in gccxml, but it seems some problem with my code.
I am not able to get the information passed in `__attribute` in my output.xml

Following is the simpler form of the code which I tried :

```
Input:
    [me@local bin]$ cat attribute.cpp
    class __attribute((gccxml("MyAttribute"))) SomeClass {};


Output:
    [me@local bin]$ ./gccxml attribute.cpp -fxml=xmlattribute.xml
    [me@local bin]$ cat xmlattribute.xml
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <GCC_XML>
      <Namespace id="_1" name="::" members="_3 "/>
      <Namespace id="_2" name="std" context="_1" members=""/>
      <Class id="_3" name="SomeClass" context="_1" location="f0:1" members="_4 _5 " bases=""/>
      <Constructor id="_4" name="SomeClass" context="_3" location="f0:1">
        <Argument name="_ctor_arg" type="_6"/>
      </Constructor>
      <Constructor id="_5" name="SomeClass" context="_3" location="f0:1"/>
      <ReferenceType id="_6" type="_3c"/>
      <File id="f0" name="attribute.cpp"/>
    </GCC_XML>
```

NOTE:

```
[me@local bin]$ ./gccxml --version
GCC-XML version 0.4.2
```